# A quickway to unminimize all minimized via bash prompt or some installable utility?

Tags: bash, window-management, compiz

I'm using compiz-manjaro in XFCE. Working great except for the fact that if a window is minimized in a Desktop(or Viewport as they call it in Compiz), it will not show up when using any window switching plugins restricted to that Viewport (so when switching between all the windows on all the Viewports, minimized windows do show up but when you're switching between the windows of that viewport, the minimized windows don't show up).

I'm trying to work around this limitation/bug by writing a script that will restore all minimized windows but I'm not sure what's the best way to go about it.

Someone called Greg Till wrote a python script in 2009 that uses Wnck to max all the windows before iniating Compiz Scale: http://pastebin.com/mCRKZkVb (I updated it so that it would work) but it was extremely slow about doing this.

As far as I can tell, there is no function to restore minimized windows in Compiz, otherwise I would have set keystroke for that and combined both functions in the script. Is there a ready made function in bash or some kind of utility that can install that will restore minimized windows quickly?

Comment: Write patch or feature request to xfce would be much cleaner solution. For example icewm already have this feature via `QuickSwitchToMinimized=1 # 0/1` setting.

Comment: I suggest you try `wmctrl` if applicable

Comment: That sounds like something that could be done nicely with some `xdotools` script, have you tried playing around with it?

Comment: @Jean Alexandre Yeah xdotools is great, I was already using to call up the scale plugin using combo keys. Problem is that compiz has not combo keys to unminimize minimized windows, so I can't use xdotools for that. They have a show desktop function but if you try to use show desktop when you have a mix of minimized and unminimized, it'll just minimize everything.

Comment: @Ipor Sircer Thanks for the suggestion. I'll make a feature request.

Comment: @Vlastimil Burian Thanks, I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up completely rewriting Greg Till's script with the aim of making it lighter and more efficient. I took out the functionality that restores the minimized windows back to their original minimized state after running the scale plugin as I didn't deem it essential and it was bloating the script.

I've tested the new script on both my very puny 7 year old laptop and my state of the art gaming desktop. Based on my experience I would  recommend this script for anyone with a Desktop that's newer than 5 years. Most laptops are alot slower than desktops, so I wouldn't recommend this script to anyone that doesn't have a relatively recent one or a beefy gaming laptop like the Eurocoms, Saeger, Origin PC, AW 15in or 17in (but not the 11in ones).

All the installation instructions are in the script's comments in the beginning.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Written by: Fadi R (November 2016)

# Rewrite of Greg Till's 2009 python script which get's around compiz's minimized window switching limitation
# Original Script and Thread here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=976002
# Public domain software

# Installation: 

# Install the following packages: libwnck3, xdotool, wmctrl
# In Compiz, go to Scale plugin and set "initiate window picker" to the following key combo: Ctrl-Super-Alt 1
#   if you are unhappy with combo, just change it to what you want at the end of script.
# go to "Command Plugin" and make a new command. For the actual command line itself, input /path/to/this/script/./scale.py 
#   (don't forget to give this script execute permission), once you're done with that, bind the new 
#   command to the key combination you usually use to start the scale plugin (for example Alt-Tab. Same deal for corners 
#   and buttons if you use them.

#  This script is for fast machines. I wouldn't use it on a 7 year old portable for example, it will add alot of lague.
#  On the other hand, there will be little to no lague on a relatively recent desktop or a even more recent gaming laptop 
#  with a non-bs/mobile CPU/GPU (I'm talking to you Dell).

import gi
gi.require_version('Wnck', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Wnck
import os
import subprocess


def determine_minimized(windows):
    #Determine which windows in a given list are minimized
    minimizedWindows = []
    for window in windows:
    if window.is_minimized():
            minimizedWindows.append(window)
    return minimizedWindows



def main():
        # ************************************************************************
        # Unminimize all minimized viewport windows
        # ************************************************************************
    eligibleWindows = []
    screen = Wnck.Screen.get_default()
    screen.force_update()
    allWindows = screen.get_windows_stacked()
    workspace = screen.get_active_workspace()
    for window in allWindows:
        if window.is_in_viewport(workspace):
            eligibleWindows.append(window)

    if eligibleWindows:
        minimizedWindows = determine_minimized(eligibleWindows)
    else:
        os._exit(0)


    if minimizedWindows:
            for window in minimizedWindows:
                subprocess.call('wmctrl -ia ' + str(window.get_xid()), shell=True)



    # ************************************************************************
    # Launch the Scale plugin of the Compiz window manager using hotkeys via xdotool

    subprocess.call("xdotool keydown Control keydown Super keydown Alt key 1 keyup Alt keyup Super keyup Control", shell=True)  




if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    os._exit(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I expect the following command to do the trick : `xdotool search --onlyvisible --name '.*'  windowactivate %@`.
A quick breakdown: `xdotool` is the utility we are using to manipulate windows and cursors and keyboard events from the terminal. The first part of the command, `search --onlyvisible --name '.*'`, selects the windows that we want to interact with. The `search` is pretty self-explanatory, `--onlyvisible`, means we want to search only the windows that *can* ben shown (first attempt without the `--onlyvisible` options tried to unminimize stuff like gnome-settings, completely breaking my session), and `--name '.*'` is there only because we **have** to give a match criteria on either the window's name, classname or class, so we say we want windows matching the `.*` regular expression, meaning any number of time any character, i.e. literally everything. The second part, `windowactivate %@`, means that we want to raise/unminimize (`windowactive`) every windows returned by the previous search (`%@`).

Comment: I didn't realize you could do that with xdotool, I'll give it a go thanks.

Comment: @thebunnyrules : I hope my edit work, let me know.

Comment: great work @Jean Alexandre, the line you gave me was really helpful with only one caveat: the --onlyvisible switch will only activate un-minimized windows which would defeat the purpose of the script. I removed --onlyvisible and the line worked like a charm and super fast, way faster than Greg Till's python script. I'm going to see if there is some sort of only minimized switch I can use to make the script more efficient.

Comment: I spoke too soon, removing the --onlyvisible windows has given me the same issues you got. But having it breaks the script for me. Hmmm. There must be a way of getting around that.

Comment: Ok, from what I could tell, gnome dashboard, toolbars, shell interface, seem to be all considered to be windows, removing, this is why removing --onlyvisible gives weirdness. 2 approaches I could think to get around that: easy one would be to define what typical windows classes constitute the regular windows & max them only. Not too sure how to do that. Harder way would be to make a list of all the windows that shouldn't be maximized & have xdotool minimize them after having the initial the blanket maximize. Also is there a way to get xdotool to figure out what desktop I'm on?

Comment: Contrarily to my initial thought, and what the name seems to imply, `--only-visible` does include minimized windows. I checked it on my own computer, with Gnome-Shell as the windows manager, and it worked just fine. Have you double-checked that it doesn't work with Compiz-Manjaro?

Comment: No, I had uninstalled Compiz in favor of the normal xfce window manager + xfdashboard for windows scaling until I was able to resolve the minimized window problem in Compiz. My recent tests with xdotool and the '--only-visible' switch were on the normal xfce window manager which does not seem include minimized windows as visible windows. I'll reinstall compiz and test how it reacts with the '--only-visible' switch.

Comment: I just got around to installing compiz on a new build, no dice, the --only-visible switch doesn't work on compiz either. Obviously Gnome Shell and compiz/xfce window manager have different ways of interpreting minimized windows which is probably giving us different results.

Comment: The xdotool line you gave works very well for unminimizing windows but I wasn't able to get it work with Compiz's viewports. So if I use it, it would unmin all the windows in all the view ports which breaks what I'm trying to do with it because it switches me to another viewport instead of the one I'm trying to run the scale plugin on. I ended up completly rewriting Greg Till's python script and it works really well on fast machines. Thanks for all the effort you put into trying to help me. I appreciate it.